# How to run my own program on UNIX/Linux

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I created my own program in C and I want to <strike>add it into this directory /usr/local/bin</strike> be able to *run (execute) it*.

Actually I don't know the commands for this.

Could someone help me?

Comment: how did you create a 'process' in the first place? (by the way, a process can't be copied. Files can be copied). Also [unix shell commands](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=unix+shell+commands&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Comment: yeah you are right, actually I wrote wrong. I created a c file so I have to add it.

Comment: fixed up your question a bit so people will not chase you away. You seem to have a programming question after all :)

Answer (score 3):

Re: *`I created a c file so I have to add it`*

#### A:

- no, you need to compile it

  ```
  cc myfork.c -o myfork
  ```
- and run it

  ```
   ./myfork
  ```

(wear a life vest)

**EDIT** To avoid having to 'qualify' the program name (e.g. `myfork`) with the path (like in `./myfork`) add the path to the PATH environment variable:

```
 PATH="$PWD/:$PATH"
 export PATH
```

Now you can do

```
 myfork
```

(or whatever you named your program)

Comment: Well I know it, but I need something like that: $myfork test. I have to call like this.

Comment: `$myfork test`? Perhaps you mean it needs to be called as `test`, not `./test`? In that case, just `export PATH="$PWD/:$PATH"` to include the current working dir in the path

Comment: Inside myfork.c, using execl and it shows the index of the file(e.g test.c)
I'm getting an error. Sorry I just started to use command line, I can't use it very well.
lambda05:~> export PATH="$PWD/:$PATH"
export: Command not found.

Comment: test is a very dangerous name for an executable that has to be found via the PATH. There is a /bin/test, and there might even be a shell built-in. You might force the execution of the *right* test by typing /usr/local/test, but it is better to avoid the name "test" altogether.

Comment: @sehe - I think this is related to the question OP asked yesterday.  He wanted to run an external program via `execl`.  Also something involving a C program he wrote but I couldn't figure out where that entered the picture.

Comment: I just want to use myfork.c file as command (myfork) and this myfork.c file is shwoing content of its argument (e.g test.c). I just have to call like this:myfork test.c. I think it is more clear now. I checked myfork.c file if it works or not like you said (cc test.c -o test ./test ) and it works well.

Comment: @AhmetTanakol: have a look at `execlp` - it will use the path. @wildplasser has a good point on the naming of a 'globally accessible' program. Also, is anything preventing you from saying e.g. `/home/user/myfork test` in your program?

Comment: @AhmetTanakol: re 'export: command not found' you're probably using another shell (ksh,sh?); Note that I had already edited my answer with the slightly more portable (but longer) version of it that should work in POSIX shells.

Comment: execl("/bin/cat","cat","-b","-t","-v",argv[1],(char*)NULL);
This is how I wrote execl "/bin/cat" is my path

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cp prog /usr/local/bin
```

You probably need to be root (hence sudo)

If `/usr/local/bin` does not exit then do this first.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin
```

Also make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`.